# How will i make this type of list in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I want to make this type of customized list .

[image]

I have that red color image & i have to fit coming next 5 date n current month on that red image & near to that i want to add four text. I have that white background image of that list with me .
how to do it in blackberry.Please help me ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use "[Create a Custom Listfield - Change Highlight Color when Scrolling](http://berrytutorials.blogspot.com/2009/11/create-custom-listfield-change.html)" from the berrytutorials blog to learn how to create a `listField` . In the  `drawListRow` method you can get the graphics object and draw the list row as you want.

Use `graphics.drawText()` to draw text , `graphics.drawBitmap()` to draw images etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
This was my requirement Hence I did not go for the listField option...
Try it may be helpful..

listVFM = new VerticalFieldManager();

rowHFM = new HorizontalFieldManager[10];

imageBitmapField = new BitmapField[10];

img_bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("image.png");

descriptionLabel = new LabelField[10];

discountLabel = new LabelField[10];

goButton = new RoundedCustomButtonField[10];

goSelectBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("btnSelectGo.png");

goUnselectBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("btnUnselectGo.png");


row_height = 90;

int j=0;

int row_count = 0;

for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {

    rowHFM[row_count] = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT) {

        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

            int displayWidth = Display.getWidth();
            int displayHeight = 80;

            super.sublayout( displayWidth, displayHeight);
            setExtent( displayWidth, displayHeight);
        }

    };


    rowHFM[row_count].setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

    imageBitmapField[row_count] = new BitmapField(img_bitmap, BitmapField.FIELD_VCENTER | BitmapField.VCENTER |                     BitmapField.USE_ALL_HEIGHT) {

        protected void layout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
        {
            int displayWidth = 85;
            int displayHeight = 70;

            super.layout( displayWidth, displayHeight);
            setExtent( displayWidth, displayHeight);
        }   
    };

    imageBitmapField[row_count].setPadding(0,0,0,4);


    descriptionLabel[row_count] = new LabelField("Description.....") {

        protected void layout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

            int displayWidth = (int)(Display.getWidth()/2.6);
            int displayHeight = maxHeight;

            super.layout( displayWidth, displayHeight);
            setExtent( displayWidth, displayHeight);
        }   

    };


    descriptionLabel[row_count].setPadding(5,0,0,2);

    discountLabel[row_count] = new LabelField(discountRate + "%") {

        protected void layout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

            int displayWidth = (int)(Display.getWidth()/4.8);
            int displayHeight = maxHeight;

            super.layout( displayWidth, displayHeight);
            setExtent( displayWidth, displayHeight);
        }   

    };


    discountLabel[row_count].setPadding(5,0,0,2);

    goButton[row_count] = new CustomButtonField("go",goSelectBitmap ,goUnselectBitmap, Field.FIELD_VCENTER              |Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT);



    goButton[row_count].setPadding(0,0,0,2);

    goButton[row_count].setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

            //code....
        }

    });

    rowHFM[row_count].add(imageBitmapField[row_count]);

    rowHFM[row_count].add(descriptionLabel[row_count]);

    rowHFM[row_count].add(discountLabel[row_count]);

    rowHFM[row_count].add(goButton[row_count]);

    listVFM.add(rowHFM[row_count]);

    row_count++;

}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution for several reasons. Say if  i have even a hundred rows, it would create several hundred fields and managers which will affect the performance of the app. Also, this would fail miserably if used for devices with small screens like pearl etc.

Comment: @user1121332: yeah yeah I definately agree.. But for me the requirement was not of 100 records... and had some issues in using ListField. Hence, went for this method.